# Strange behavior on static members of a class - How's this possible?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, static-members, static-classes

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string[] SomeAmazingConsts = { Const1 };
    public static string Const1 = "Constant 1";
    public static string Const2 = "Constant 2";
}
```

Now, check out the usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] s = MyClass.SomeAmazingConsts;
        //s[0] == null
    }
}
```

The problem is that s[0] == null! How the heck does this happen? Now, reorder the static variable of MyClass as follows:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string Const1 = "Constant 1";
    public static string Const2 = "Constant 2";
    public static string[] SomeAmazingConsts = { Const1 };
}
```

Things start to work properly. Anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: You are assigning a null reference to the array, it can not magically get re-assigned with the modified value

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From [10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a
>   sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in
>   which they appear in the class declaration.

So the initialization happens top to bottom, and in the first case `Const1` has not been initialized, hence the `null`

Comment: So why the compiler doesn't stop me at "public static string[] SomeAmazingConsts = { Const1 };" line? Since the Const1 is a static variable and it's not initialized yet, they could (?) stop me from using it before it's defined in the first place. BTW, how can I make sure that reordering doesn't affect the code execution? Any advice?

Comment: I use ReSharper, and the message (be it warning only) states *Static field initializer refers to static field below or in other part*. So you might want to consider using a code analysis tool rather? Also, your variable is defined in the correct scope, it is just not initialized at the time.

Comment: One obvious solution is declare the string array as a property: public static string[] SomeAmazingConsts { get { return new string[] { Const1 }; } } But is it ok to do that?

Comment: That will depend on the expected behaviour, as a property will allow for changes in `Const1` to filter through to the reference of `SomeAmazingConsts` where as your current setup doesnt.